gedit opening on linux box instead of in X server over SSH
I am connecting to an Ubuntu 22.04 machine using PuTTy and Xming from a windows 11 laptop. When I try to open gedit, the window does open, but it opens on the linux box and not over the SSH. All other programs open in Xming like expected. How can I get gedit to open on the remote machine rather than the host? I have never seen it work this way, where sending the command over SSH causes the window to open on the linux machine. Google hasn't been helpful.

YES, sorry, PuTTY and Xming.
